"failed go start load apparmor profiles managed by snapd" while booting Ubuntu 22.04
I shutdown the laptop (Ubuntu 22.04) normally yesterday, and today when I tried to boot Ubuntu 22.04 it is not booting and giving me an error:

Somehow I went to root terminal and did following:



Then I found one solution on Ask Ubuntu (here) that is go to a root terminal and run following command:
sudo apt install apparmor-easyprof

It is giving me Unable to locate package apparmor-easyprof. I have tried to disable apparmor and then enabled it, but nothing worked for me yet.
How can I resolve this problem and boot my Ubuntu?

I stumbled upon this old bug report. Please try and run:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor

without entering anything when prompted for additional home directory locations.
It should re-create (or update) /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu; if that alone doesn't work, try and remove /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu and run the command again.
Some people commenting report being able to solve the issue by entering /home/ instead of nothing, but as far as I understand this shouldn't be necessary.
The prompt is asking for additional home directory locations, and unless your /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home file doesn't contain @{HOMEDIRS}=/home/ already (it should contain it by default / less /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home to verify this), there's no reason to add /home/ to /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/ubuntu as well (and I'd argue in that case one should rather change /etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home so that it contains /home/ and then run sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor without entering anything when prompted for additional home directory locations).
